# install skype 4.3 but only 4.2 installs

Tags: skype

so ive been trying everything to install 4.3, but whenever i install it, weather through gdebi, or the software center, it says its installing 4.3, but then when i open it only 4.2 is installed. 
i would have no problem with 4.2, but 4.2 does not connect my password and everything are right, but it always says "skype can't connect"
am i doing something wrong here, or has anyone else faced this issue? 
i heard some people discribe a .skype appearing in their home folder, but none is there for me when i click home. so im clueless here :-(

Comment: it's a bug https://launchpad.net/bugs/1372846 the method (by removing older verion and using the deb download works). Using the normal version from USC got me 4.2 even though USC shows that it is 4.3 you selected. Annoying but easy to circumvent :)

Answer (score -1):

When installing from Canonical Partner, make sure to install both the skype and skype-bin packages. So if you use a terminal window, you need to:

```
sudo apt-get install skype skype-bin
```

That should install the latest (4.3) version.

This is an example of an upgrade from Skype 4.2 to 4.3:

```
$ dpkg-query -W skype skype-bin
skype   4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
skype-bin   4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
$ sudo apt-get install skype skype-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  skype skype-bin
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 20,1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 5 106 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ utopic/partner skype-bin i386 4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 [20,1 MB]
Get:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ utopic/partner skype i386 4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 [16,1 kB]
Fetched 20,1 MB in 7s (2 828 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 511027 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../skype-bin_4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking skype-bin (4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) over (4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../skype_4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking skype (4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) over (4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.10.20140925-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.55ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.8.8-1ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up skype-bin (4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
Setting up skype (4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
$ dpkg-query -W skype skype-bin
skype   4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
skype-bin   4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
```

Comment: You did not address his problem: he claims he is getting 4.2 when he uses Ubuntu Software Center and wants to install 4.3. All you do is tell him what he already did try.

Comment: @Rinzwind: I don't agree. Most likely the OP tried to update the `skype` package only, which ought to be sufficient, but due to the bug you mentioned in a comment, it's not. Adding `skype-bin` to the list of packages to install indeed addresses the problem.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Personally I think it's a very annoying bug, and I'm thinking of suggesting that they either start maintaining skype in Canonical Partner properly, or drop it from there completely.

Comment: Like I said: if you have older skype installed you have to remove it or it will not install the new one. That's the bug. Using the DEB download does work to install 4.3. My solution works perfectly. Yours will -NOT- if skype is already installed.

Comment: @Rinzwind: What's so hard to understand with what I wrote? I edited my answer to make my point - only for you. ;)